# Comparing with LAG Analytic function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, lag, window-functions

I am using oracle PL/SQL.

I am trying to compare column values with `LAG` function.
Following is the statement:

```
decode(LAG(col1,1) OVER (ORDER BY col3),col1,'No Change','Change_Occured') Changes
```

As for first row, LAG will always compare with the previous empty row. So for my query the first row of column `'Changes'` is always showing the value as `Change_Occured` when in fact no change has happened. Is there any way to handle this scenario ?

Assume this table:

```
| col1 | col2 | 
|  2   | 3    |
|  2   | 6    |
|  2   | 7    |
|  2   | 9    |
```

Each row of `col1` is compared with previous value so result will be

```
| col1 | col2 | Changes        |
|  2   | 3    | Change_occured |
|  2   | 9    | No Change      |
|  2   | 5    | No Change      |
|  2   | 8    | No Change      |
```

So how should I handle the first row of column `Changes`

Comment: Please provide the sample data and show your expected output.

Comment: I have added default data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for **LAG** Analytic function is:

```
LAG  (value_expression [,offset] [,default]) OVER ([query_partition_clause] order_by_clause)
```

- default - The value returned if the offset is outside the scope of the window. The default value is NULL.

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 2 col1, 3 col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2 col1, 6 col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2 col1, 7 col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2 col1, 9 col2 FROM dual
  6  )
  7  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
  8  SELECT col1, LAG(col1,1) OVER (ORDER BY col2) changes FROM sample_data;

      COL1    CHANGES
---------- ----------
         2
         2          2
         2          2
         2          2
```

Therefore, in the **DECODE** expression you are comparing the **NULL** value with a real value and it is evaluated as `Change_Occurred`

You could use the **default value** as the column value itself:

```
DECODE(LAG(col1,1, col1) OVER (ORDER BY col2),col1,'No Change','Change_Occured') Changes
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 2 col1, 3 col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2 col1, 6 col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2 col1, 7 col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2 col1, 9 col2 FROM dual
  6  )
  7  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
  8  SELECT col1,
  9         DECODE(
 10                LAG(col1,1, col1) OVER (ORDER BY col2),
 11                col1,
 12                'No Change',
 13                'Change_Occured'
 14               ) Changes
 15  FROM sample_data;

      COL1 CHANGES
---------- --------------
         2 No Change
         2 No Change
         2 No Change
         2 No Change

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be:

```
decode(LAG(col1,1, col1) OVER (ORDER BY col3),col1,'No Change','Change_Occured') Changes
```

The optional default value is returned if the offset goes beyond the scope of the window. If you do not specify default, then its default is null.